# New shell should be invocated from previous working directory

Tags: csh

Hi can somebody help me in writing a .cshrc script which always starts a new terminal from my previous working directory.

Also it should set some environment variable based on the same.

The exact requirement can be explained as:

Say I was working in one Terminal/Konsole-A and the directory I was working on was ~/A/B/C
now when I open a new Terminal/Konsole-B it should be pointing me in the Dir ~/A/B/C

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running `tcsh` not `csh` this is quite easy:

```
alias cwdcmd 'dirs -S ~/.cshdirs'
```

This uses the fact that `tcsh -l` (a login shell) automatically runs `dirs -L ~/.cshdirs`.

If you are using a plain `csh` you'd have to create an alias for `cd` like so:

```
if ( -f ~/.cshdir ) then
  cd `cat ~/.cshdir`
  echo -n "Changed back to "; pwd
endif
alias cd 'cd \!*; pwd >! ~/.cshdir'
```

I haven't tested the latter as I only run `tcsh` myself.